# Connect areas on a grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, pseudocode, flood-fill

I have a tile grid. It is a 2d array of booleans. 'false' means an empty square, 'true' means a wall. I need to connect all of the empty areas by removing the walls. So far all of my ideas were pretty inefficient.

The only guarantee is that all of the empty regions are separated by a one wall thick layer. I would prefer if there were no loops (once two regions are connected no more walls are removed that would reconnect those two regions)

A sample grid (# for wall, . for empty space):

```
############
#....#.....#
#..##....###
#..#...##..#
######.#...#
#...#..#...#
#....####..#
#.....#....#
############
```

any algorithms or pseudo code to help with this is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for minimum spanning tree algorithm, for example [Kruskal's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) (assuming you need to remove minimal amount of walls)

any empty region would be a vertex in the graph, and those of them which could be connected by removing a piece of wall would have an edge among them (in your case only of weight 1).

Comment: According to your logic you need to just find *any* spanning tree, which you can do using a simple DFS. However, you might be able to connect more than two regions (up to 4) by removing only a single wall, so your construction does not work.

Comment: Thank you. I knew there must be an algorithm for what I was looking for I just didn't know the name. So I assume I would flood fill the regions and then randomly remove a wall that connects the two to build the spanning tree?

Comment: Yes, basically. But it won't give you an optimal solution as I suggested in the second sentence of my comment, see e.g. "#.#\n.#.\n#.#". The answer is 1, but every spanning tree has 3 edges